# PHP remove csv row by other csv

Tags: php, csv

[root@localhost TEST]# cat v.csv 
S02,
S03,
S07,

[root@localhost TEST]# cat test.csv 
S01,172.16.20.222,10.10.10.100,445 
S02,10.10.10.10,192.168.100.100,22 
S03,10.10.10.10,192.168.100.100,22 
S04,172.16.20.222,10.10.10.103,23 
S05,100.100.100.100,192.168.100.100,22 
S06,192.168.200.10,192.168.100.100,22 
S07,10.10.10.10,192.168.100.100,22 
S08,192.168.100.100,10.10.100.106,446 
S09,172.16.20.223,10.10.10.108,447 
S10,192.168.100.100,10.10.10.109,448

Howto remove S02, S03,S07, in test.csv by  v.csv

Answer (score 0):

$table = fopen('test.csv','r');
$temp_table = fopen('temp.csv','w');
$id = 'S01"; ##// the name of the column you're looking for
while (($data = fgetcsv($table, 1000)) !== FALSE){
    if(reset($data) == $id){ // this is if you need the first column in a row
        continue;
    }
    fputcsv($temp_table,$data);
}
fclose($table);
fclose($temp_table);
rename('temp.csv','test.csv');